# Does Core Data exist on the iPhone? Or how would you save Data on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

Lets say I make an App that enables users to make short notes and write things down.
Is there Core Data on iPhone OS too?
Or how else would you save that data in iPhone?

Comment: have you seen this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443223/data-store-for-a-mac-iphone-hybrid-app

Answer (score 7):

No. Core Data, and Cocoa Bindings, as well as Objective-C Garbage Collection are all missing from the iPhone.

Update: As mentioned below, Core Data is available with iPhone OS 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

If you can wait for iPhone OS 3.0, Apple's preview movie lists Core Data as one of the new features in 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite is generally the preferred storage method if you have a lot of data. You can code the SQL classes by hand, or there are a number of nice third-party solutions.

For smaller amounts of information, you can easily store data in a file using NSCoding and NSArchiver.

Answer (score 3):

I'll reiterate the above, but you could have a look at [OmniDataObjects](http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/) which provides Core Data-esque functionality and runs on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do some ordering or querying on the saved data, the best solution is SQLite.
Otherwise you can use serialized data. NSDictionary and NSArray provides -writeToFile methods to write serialized (in xml format) data to file.

Marco

Answer (score 1):

depending upon the complexity, you can save your data on sqlite database, plist files, or even create your own xml files and save them on iphone file system (usually in the documents directory)

if you dont anticipate too many reads / writes / complex lookups then stick to plist files or xml files

however anything more complex, go ahead with sqlite.

if you do go ahead with sqlite then i would suggest you to use [FMDB](http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/03/fmdb_for_iphone.html) - a cocoa wrapper for sqlite, this saves you tons of repetitive code

Answer (score -1):

Data saving on the iPhone is not much different - write the data to a file (like a plist). As far as I know, there's no iPhone Core Data.